# C# Conditional Formatting on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Cells based on cell text

Tags: c#, excel-formula, excel-interop

I write a code with C# and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. In generated a drop-down list where one can chose between "okay", "delete", "else". Now I want that the cell becomes red if "delete" is chosen. I tried to do this with `Excel.FormatCondition`:

```
Excel.FormatCondition condition = mysheet.get_Range("J2:J10",
    Type.Missing).FormatConditions.Add(Type:Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString,
    Operator: Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, Formula1: "=\"delete\"");
condition.Interior.ColorIndex = 3;
```

With this code I get an error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800A03EC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but hopefully this might help someone else.
When you set the type to `Type:Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString`, you need to set the `String:` and `TextOperator:` parameters and not `Operator:` and `Formula1:` as shown in the question.

Fixing the code:

```
FormatConditions.Add(Type:Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlTextString,
    TextOperator: Excel.XlContainsOperator.xlContains, String: "delete");
```